# Query Selector To Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having this html page ( inside the body tag ) ->

```
<div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list">
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Iteasm</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Iteasm</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Iteasm</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Item</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Item</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Item</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Item</li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to querySelect the .todo-list  and want to convert the innerText to array..
I tried the what is told [here](https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/converting-a-node-list-to-an-array/)  but is not working->

```
const nodelist = document.querySelector('.todo-list').innerText;
const nodelistToArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist);
console.log(nodelistToArray);
```

But I am getting this in the console ->

```
["I", "t", "e", "a", "s", "m", "↵", "I", "t", "e", "a", "s", "m", "↵", "I", "t", "e", "a", "s", "m", "↵", "I", "t", "e", "m", "↵", "I", "t", "e", "m", "↵", "I", "t", "e", "m", "↵", "I", "t", "e", "m"]
```

Actually I want something like this ->

```
["Iteasm", "Iteasm", "Iteasm"]
```

Any idea ??
Thanks !!!

Comment: You can't place a `li` element inside a `div`. A `div` inside a `ul` is also forbidden. Please remove all the `div`s inside your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` instead, and `Array.from`:

```js
console.log(
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('.todo > li'),
    li => li.textContent
  )
);
```

```html
<div class="todo-container">
  <ul class="todo-list">
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Iteasm</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Iteasm</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Iteasm</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Item</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Item</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Item</li>
    </div>
    <div class="todo">
      <li>Item</li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Very very thanks CertainPerformance !!! It worked fine !!!

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this

```
const items = [...document.getElementsByClassName("todo")].map(li => li.innerText);
console.log(items);
```